# Export multiple tables from SQL developer into a single excel

Tags: sql, excel, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, export-to-excel

I would like to export (some of) the contents of multiple tables I can see with Oracle SQL Developer into a single excel file. This is, I expect one sheet with several sheets - one for each table.

However, when the export is finished, the excel file has only the sheet of the last table I selected.

Could it be that SQL Developer keeps overwriting the same .xlsx file all along the export process? Or is it a bug (I have version 17.3.1 of Oracle SQL Developer)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SQL Developer, select one or more tables, views, MV's and drag-n-drop them to the Cart.

The Cart is a panel available from the View menu.

Once there, uncheck DDL, and check the Data boxes.

Add filters for the data as appropriate.

Hit the Export Cart button.

Choose - Single File.
Choose - XLSX.

SQL Developer will export each data set to a separate workbook in your Excel file.

Note: there was a bug in previous versions of the application that prevented this from working. Upgrade to version 17.4 and it will work just fine.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

(Oh, that!) Jeff Smith knows it: [Exporting Multiple Tables to Multiple Excel Spreadsheets](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2016/01/exporting-multiple-tables-to-multiple-excel-spreadsheets/)

Comment: That is the theory and it is what I was expecting, but for some reason it didn't work for me: it only produced an excel with one sheet

Comment: was a bug, fixed in version 17.4, proof here :) https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DTRGGU2XkAAe8iy.jpg:large

Comment: @thatjeffsmith That was exactly what I was looking for! I reinstalled my SQL Developer and it worked. Make your comment and answer and I will gladly accept it

Answer (score 0):

Use CNTRL to select the tables and then right click to select EXPORT option. Then select'format' as xlsx/csv/xls etc etc. Give the location to save the file. Boom you got your table dumps in an excel

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).